# Streamlit-webrtc camera not displaying the video [ python ]

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, streamlit

i am building a faceattendance app with streamlit-webrtc. when i try to start the camera , it loads for a while and then stops trying, after some seconds, I got the below log error. anyone help me to solve this error?

app - https://faceattendance-zwsstkqbylvrej2rmspke6.streamlit.app/

repo - GitHub - https://github.com/swaminathan33/faceattendance/

```
[02:16:50]  Python dependencies were installed from /app/faceattendance/requirements.txt using pip.

[02:16:50]  Processed dependencies!

  Stopping...

[02:16:51] ❗️ The service has encountered an error while checking the health of the Streamlit app: Get "http://localhost:8501/healthz": dial tcp 10.12.210.84:8501: connect: connection refused


Collecting usage statistics. To deactivate, set browser.gatherUsageStats to False.





[02:16:53]  Updated app!

Exception in callback Transaction.__retry()

handle: <TimerHandle when=40048.736591604 Transaction.__retry()>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1054, in sendto

    self._sock.sendto(data, addr)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendto'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run

    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aioice/stun.py", line 312, in __retry

    self.__protocol.send_stun(self.__request, self.__addr)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aioice/ice.py", line 266, in send_stun

    self.transport.sendto(bytes(message), addr)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1064, in sendto

    self._fatal_error(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 711, in _fatal_error

    self._loop.call_exception_handler({

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call_exception_handler'

Exception in callback Transaction.__retry()

handle: <TimerHandle when=40048.943397949 Transaction.__retry()>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1054, in sendto

    self._sock.sendto(data, addr)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendto'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run

    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aioice/stun.py", line 312, in __retry

    self.__protocol.send_stun(self.__request, self.__addr)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aioice/ice.py", line 266, in send_stun

    self.transport.sendto(bytes(message), addr)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1064, in sendto

    self._fatal_error(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 711, in _fatal_error

    self._loop.call_exception_handler({

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call_exception_handler'

Exception in callback Transaction.__retry()

handle: <TimerHandle when=40062.850545854 Transaction.__retry()>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1054, in sendto

    self._sock.sendto(data, addr)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendto'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run

    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aioice/stun.py", line 312, in __retry

    self.__protocol.send_stun(self.__request, self.__addr)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aioice/ice.py", line 266, in send_stun

    self.transport.sendto(bytes(message), addr)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1064, in sendto

    self._fatal_error(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 711, in _fatal_error

    self._loop.call_exception_handler({

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call_exception_handler'

Exception in callback Transaction.__retry()

handle: <TimerHandle when=40078.795474807 Transaction.__retry()>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1054, in sendto

    self._sock.sendto(data, addr)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendto'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run

    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aioice/stun.py", line 312, in __retry

    self.__protocol.send_stun(self.__request, self.__addr)

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aioice/ice.py", line 266, in send_stun

    self.transport.sendto(bytes(message), addr)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1064, in sendto

    self._fatal_error(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 711, in _fatal_error

    self._loop.call_exception_handler({

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call_exception_handler'
```

main.py

```
# trying using streamlit webrtc

import streamlit as st
from streamlit_webrtc import webrtc_streamer
import numpy as np
import av
import cv2

SKLEARN_ALLOW_DEPRECATED_SKLEARN_PACKAGE_INSTALL=True

def hello(frame):
    
    img = frame.to_ndarray(format='bgr24')

    cv2.putText(img, 'Match !', (20, 450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 0), 3)

    return av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(img, format="bgr24")

webrtc_streamer(key='hello', video_frame_callback=hello)
```

i deployed my app in streamlit cloud .

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: what do you have before `"During handling of the above exception"`? There should be more useful information.

Comment: now i updated it .